# IronPDF MarginLeft and MarginRight does not work in Landscape PaperOrientation?

Tags: c#, pdf, pdf-generation, html-to-pdf, ironpdf

I am trying to convert HTML template to PDF using IronPDF's `HtmlToPdf()`.

I have following settings for `PdfPrintOptions`

```
Dpi = 600,
EnableJavaScript = true,
PaperOrientation = PdfPrintOptions.PdfPaperOrientation.Landscape,
PaperSize = PdfPrintOptions.PdfPaperSize.A4,
MarginBottom = 10,
MarginRight = 10,
MarginTop = 10,
MarginLeft = 10
```

In the generated PDF file, Margin for Top and Bottom is applied. But a default margin is seen on Left and Right. It doesn't change after changing option values for MarginLeft and MarginRight.

When `PdfPaperOrientation` is set as `Portrait`, all the margins are applied as per the provided values.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Were you able to figure out how to resolve this issue? I'm not having the same issue, but could be related.

Comment: @dmoore1181, nope. I raised a ticket and they came back saying put the x margins as 0 and it will work.. But to be honest it is not a solution as I would need some margin there..

So to accommodate my content on a single page I just reduced font size, keeping the margins as they are.